# Top horizontal menu Prestashop 1.6

Tags: css, menu, prestashop

Recently I started a small online shop and I have a problem with the top horizontal menu in Prestashop 1.6.

When I activate the Top horizontal menu is not horizontal, is vertical. It's like it does not have css style.

Can you help me with this issue please ?

[image]

Comment: Your code or link please

Comment: http://bitspark-brasov.ddns.net , I don't have the code right now. And I didn't change the code at all.

Comment: `float:left` or `display:inline-block` try this to `li` items

Comment: It's working but it does not have the same style like default theme. How can I change to default ?

Comment: I don't understand what is default theme? Post a pics of desired output

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to Modules> Modules > Top Menu > Reset just the parameters, you will get the default structure back.

Answer (score 2):

The default blocktopmenu in Prestashop (1.6) has 2 CSS files located in 
"prestashop/modules/blocktopmenu/":

- superfishmodified.css
- blocktopmenu.css

If you want to overwrite these default css styles you have to create exact the same css files in your theme folder in the exact same hierarchy "themes/default_bootstrap/css/modules/blocktopmenu/"

**Try the following**

But in your case your best option is to try and delete the css files of the blocktopmenu in "/themes/default_bootstrap/css/modules/blocktopmenu/"

after you delete the css files there Prestashop will switch back to the default css files located in "/modules/blocktopmenu/" delete the files in the red circle. But it's always safe to backup these 2 files first just in case.

[image: See picture]

Other options is to download a fresh copy of the Prestashop version you're using and replace both the superfishmodified.css and the blocktopmenu.css.

Answer (score 0):

The `blocktopmenu.php` loads `css` and `js` only if you add a hook to your header.

Manage hooks and insert `Top horizontal menu` to `displayHeader`. By default the hooks are just under `actionCategoryUpdate` and `displayTop`.

Refer the File:
https://github.com/PrestaShop/blocktopmenu/blob/master/blocktopmenu.php